# Automation Notfications when delete record

Tags: acumatica

I created the notifications for a screen. When I edited something in that screen and saved, the system generated a notification. Now I want when I delete a record that the system also generates a notification. Is there any way without coding to solve it?

Example:

I delete a record in Item Classes and I want to receive notification in Send Notifications Screen.

[image]

Comment: Add your code please.

Comment: Thank you for your interested with my problem.I mean how can I solve it without coding.I only manipulate on screen.Can you help me ?

Comment: Which version of Acumatica do you use?

Comment: Version 5.30.2936

Comment: Yes, you can solve it without coding. You can ask somebody else to code instead of you